# How to use IN keyword in JOIN clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I have the following SQL query. How can I create the same query in LINQ?

```
select * from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1
where t2.col2 in ('A','B','C' )
```

Comment: I assume you mean using an ORM such as Entity Framework? You would really need to tell us which ORM it is and what your c# classes look like to help you properly

Comment: this is using CRM Linq provider

Comment: Are you using late or early bound?

Comment: @Sxntk: I'm using late binding

Comment: I was able to figure it out with the below link:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943728/linq-to-dynamics-crm-query-filtering-records-locally>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` :

```
string[] stringCollection = { "A", "B", "C" };
var query = from t1 in db.Table1
            join t2 in db.Table2
            on t1.col1 equals t2.col1
            where stringCollection.Contains(t2.col2)
            select new { t1, t2 };
```

Comment: I tried this, but get this error:
Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.

Comment: @Payal: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200034/trying-to-execute-a-where-in-invalid-where-condition-an-entity-member-is-inv) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881302/equivalent-to-sql-in-clause) helps.

Comment: This is how i have my current LINQ query:
(from t1 in table1
                                 join t2 in table2
                                 on t1.col1 equals t2.col1
                                 where t1.col2 == someStatusfield
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     A = t1,
                                     B = t2.col2
                                 }).Where(r => r.B.Trim() == variable).ToList();

instead of .Where(r => r.B.Trim() == variable), I need to use SQL IN keyword with a list of string.

Comment: Thank you, so Contains will not work. How will it work with the above linq query that I added?

Comment: @Payal: sorry, i'm not familiar with [MS Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681573.aspx). Maybe the links i have provided are helpful. All providers i've used so far support `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query in LinQ - Crm with 'IN'.

What you can do is retrieve the records, after you have a `List<Entityt>` you use LinQ or a foreach to filter the records you need.